# Cocoa File-/Directory Watch Library available?

Tags: cocoa, fsevents

I know that there is the FSEvents Api and some Spotlight API to create a File- / Directory Watcher. I also know that there are some ObjC wrappers for FSEvents like CDEvents but is there anywhere a complete Cocoa Library for File-/Folder Watching? I can't believe that everyone creates his own Filewatcher using those really good wrappers. That means that everyone does the same work over and over again?! I'm looking for a library that can tell if and what changed in a Directory and as far as I know the finer granularity of FSEvents works only in 10.8?

kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you've found so far is what you get: FSEvents and third-party wrappers.

Comment: A few wrappers: https://github.com/rastersize/CDEvents, https://github.com/bdkjones/VDKQueue, _etc_.